# Trouble using Grant and Revoke

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am just trying to grant/deny securables to users in my database. For example, this is one of my revoke statements

USE MY_DB;
REVOKE ALTER FROM [UserName];
GO

When I view the permissions using SELECT FROM MyDB.sys.database_permissions it says the user still has the permission. How do you actually revoke a permission?

Comment: After executing the query, do a refresh on the user lists.  Then pick the user and go to properties.  It's likely what you are seeing is simply Management Studio "helpfully" caching things

Comment: Tried that already, still shows the user has permission after refreshing the database, users, and the user fields. I even restarted the database after executing the query and refreshed the fields but still the user has the permission

Answer (score 0):

If the user had broader permissions that included the specific securable and you `revoke`d a narrower permission on that securable, the user will still have the permission `grant`ed by the broader-scoped `grant`.

You may need to consider a `deny` on a securable if you want an exception to a broadly-scoped grant.

EDIT:

Given your SQL:

```
USE MY_DB; REVOKE ALTER FROM [UserName]; GO
```

... You need to specify just which securable's `ALTER` permission you're revoking: `ALTER ENDPOINT` or `ALTER LOGIN`

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186260.aspx) for the applicability of the ALTER permission, E.g.:

```
REVOKE ALTER LOGIN FROM [UserName]
```

Comment: I tried that but the issue still persists. I can modify the permissions easily using the SQL Server Management Studio, but I cannot get it to work using T-SQL.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some specifics to the SQL you entered in your question.

Comment: The example you posted gives me a syntax error. I also manually removed the user from all database memberships and server memberships. I also cleared him from all owned schemas and revoked all of his server securable permissions. However, still when I try to revoke his database securable permissions using T-SQL nothing happens. It seems strange that I can still revoke his database securable permissions using the management studio, but I cannot through T-SQL.